# Audio stopped working on HP laptop with Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, audio

Dual-booting Windows and Linux Mint an HP laptop. Audio working fine for a day or so. Other person who uses the computer booted into Windows and made something in Paint.NET, once I booted back into Mint, audio stopped playing out of the built-in speakers.

Pavucontrol lists the device, and even shows the volume spike when I'm playing sounds, but it just doesn't go through to the hardware. This now leads me to believe that it's more of a hardware/driver issue than a software problem that restarting audio services will fix.

Result of inxi -A:

```
Audio
Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
Sound server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-48-generic
```

Fixes that have failed:

- restarting pulseaudio
- reinstalling pulseaudio
- force reloading ALSA

Please help, I have online school tomorrow (but I guess I can use the proprietary garbage that is Windows if I really have to.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by you the software side is working properly.

It would be better to reboot the system to make linux kernel reconfigure/in a sense reboot the hardware side.

this type of problem may arise due to some issues in the hardware drivers.preferably also update the drivers for linux if provided by the laptop manufacturer or any trusted driver distributor.

The above statements are based on testing done on the ubuntu installed on HP laptop.the results may vary on your side.

Comment: I rebooted into an older kernel and it worked. Thank you